# Beginners question: why adding these loop edges @ around 6:20

Tags: modeling, looping

beginners question: why adding these loop edges @ around 6:20﻿:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AMXcQ2V-VGA
What is that good for?
Thanks for any hint/ link!

Comment: Refer to [link](https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2018/1/17/creating-an-anvil-full-series) Part 3: Sharpening Edges approximate time 4 min for explanation.

Comment: I would suggest putting the loops in as shown, assigning the subdiv. modifier, (Catmull-Clark) and then: 1. GG. sliding them towards and away from the edges parallel to them, and 2. Ctrl-X dissolving them. Then you will see exactly what they are doing.